# How do I get the jquery-cookie plugin to work with Rails 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-cookie

I want to use `Rails 5.0.1` and I also need the jQuery cookie plugin in my application.  I had included this in my `Gemfile`

```
gem 'jquery-cookie-rails'
```

but since changing my `Rails dependency to 5.0.1`, I now get this error when I run `bundle install` ...

```
localhost:myproject davea$ bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (= 5.0.1)

  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.2.x, >= 4.0.0)

    jquery-cookie-rails was resolved to 0.1.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.2.0)

    jquery-rails was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0)

    jquery-turbolinks was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1.0)

    jquery-ui-rails was resolved to 6.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2.16)

    rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.1)

    sass-rails was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    web-console was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

How can I have my cake and eat it too?  I want to use the latest version of Rails and I also want to use jQuery-cookie.  How can I do that?

Comment: Surely, you meant "How can I have my cookie and eat it too?".

Answer (score 0):

Try to install updated Gem Using `gem install jquery-cookie-rails --version 1.3.1.1`, Find the latest version from [here](https://www.versioneye.com/ruby/jquery-cookie-rails/1.3.1.1)

Or
You can do like this:

must put the file `jquery.cookie.js` in the folder `vendor/assets/javascripts/`, then at the file `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` it must be called with:

```
//= require jquery.cookie
```

before

```
//= require_tree .
```

or any other require that needs `jquery.cookie`

You don't need a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RyanScottLewis/jquery-cookie-rails#no-longer-maintained-jquery-cookie-is-now-superseded-by-js-cookie-which-can-be-added-to-your-rails-pipeline-with-js_cookie_rails

What worked for me was installing this gem -> https://github.com/freego/js_cookie_rails

And use Cookies lib according to the docs -> https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#basic-usage